# Which wiring configuration is better?

Tags: electrical

I have a dimmer where the output goes to a junction box in the attic and from the junction box it goes to a light fixture.  I want to replace the light fixture in question with 2 pendent lights in different locations.

The question is: Is it better to have the junction box have two outputs so each pendent light fixture only has one wire or is it better to run one wire from the junction box to the first pendent light and in that pendent's box will be a splice to the other light?

option 1:

```
       -------pendent light
J-----<
       -------pendent light
```

option 2:

```
                                first pendent light in same box
J------first pendent light box <
                                --------second pendent light
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes no difference, generally speaking. Do the method that saves you wire and/or distributes connections more uniformly to meet box capacity standards (and make life easier).

Comment: I ended up going with option 1 since my double gang junction box has more room to splice wires together than do the ceiling boxes for light fixtures. I've always been bad at tucking wires in cramped boxes.